# preSave and postSave hooks in Phalcon Model

Tags: phalcon

I was checking the API and noticed that there are `_preSave` and `_postSave` protected methods that could be used as hooks. Is there something similar for update/delete?

I was thinking of the following

```
preSave -> fires before a Save (insert/update)
postSave -> fires after a Save (insert/update)
preInsert
postInsert
preUpdate
postUpdate
preDelete
postDelete
```

Any existing functionality that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compatible with version **0.4.5**

In PhalconPHP these hooks are effectively validation events.

```
class Robots extends Phalcon_Model_Base
{
    function beforeSave()
    {
        if ($this->year < 0) {
            echo "Year cannot be negative";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

More information about validators

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#validation-messages